# Hyperledger fabric 1.4 - [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]- endorsement failed - Error: Cannot generate uuid

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In fabric 1.4 I am getting this error while trying to do a transaction:

```
2023-10-12T18:23:14.347Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:0 - endorsement failed - Error: Cannot generate uuid
2023-10-12T18:23:14.348Z - error: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _endorse - endorsement failed::Error: Endorsement has failed
    at DiscoveryEndorsementHandler._endorse (/home/fishnak/coding/hyperledger/_Metasurance/backend_api/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/DiscoveryEndorsementHandler.js:185:19)
```

Peer logs say

```
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.609 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 07d unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.1:48266 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=427.601µs
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.621 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 07e unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.1:48266 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.594403ms
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.637 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 07f [commonchannel][c4e2a523] Entry chaincode: name:"user_cc" 
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.638 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 080 [commonchannel][c4e2a523] Exit chaincode: name:"user_cc"  (1ms)
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.638 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 081 [commonchannel][c4e2a523] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"user_cc"  response status 500 for txid: c4e2a523c8b1dcb92937bfdbcac798136d2e2f5e6c6e8acc2872deacf963cecf
2023-10-13 00:04:53 2023-10-12 18:34:53.638 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 082 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.1:48286 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=2.068505ms
```

How to fix this?
The full code can be found here for reference: https://github.com/aritroCoder/_Metasurance
The `backend` folder contains Hyperledger fabric configs.